# Create Image Classification for detecting floor plans vs real estate photos

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am working in a real estate company and i would like to write a program that can figure out(classify) if an image is a floor plan or a random real estate picture (room/kitchen/outdour)

I have tried to make a classifier that works good but who make some mistakes. I have used Lenet architecture. I would like some ideas to improve the result.

Example :

floor plan :

https://photo.superimmo.com/photos/listings/1/1/f/e/1/11fe1e7920edca467277daa1878d8fd15a381f49-widest.jpg

random :
https://photo.superimmo.com/photos/listings/1/e/e/6/7/1ee67c296239ebcd3a8e53e39836011209c61a33-widest.jpg

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
model = LeNet.build(width=28, height=28, depth=1, classes=2)
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: I think increasing the width and height would help. 28x28 is pretty small and you probably lose some important information that can be used for classification. Another thing you can try is choosing a more elaborate CNN architecture. lenet is fast and simple but has to few layers to learn complicated patterns. Training on more data is also something you could try (if you have more data that is). Lastly you could increase the number of data augmentation operations or try different hyper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have concrete code examples. Here's a list of things that stand out to me:

- Floorplans are usually black and white (little color, and little grays)
- Floorplans have long well defined edges and no gradients
- Floorplans are a large percent just white
- Floorplans have edges that are perfectly horizontal and vertical
- Random pictures have colors in R, G and B
- Random pictures have bigger image size for similar resolution and compression

If you make sure some of these features can be detected by the first layer of nodes in your neural net, that might improve it.